# Send parse push notification on button click android

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

What I need is when the user clicks on a button, a push notification will be sent to all users using this app.
I tried using this code in a setOnclickListener method, but nothing was sent after clicking on it.

> Note: Sending a push notification from Parse Dashboard works perfectly
>   fine.

```
        ParsePush parsePush = new ParsePush();
        ParseQuery query = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
        parsePush.setQuery(query);
        parsePush.setMessage("A new file has been Updated. Check it out!");
        parsePush.sendInBackground(new SendCallback() {

            @Override
            public void done(ParseException arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d(TAG, "SendCallback success:");
                if(arg0 == null)
                {
                    Log.d(TAG,
                            "suceess push notification :");
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.d(TAG,
                            "failed push notification  :"
                                    + arg0.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**- EDIT - in response to Bradley Wilson's answer**
- this still did not work

```
ParsePush parsePush = new ParsePush();
ParseQuery<ParseInstallation> parseQueryInstallation = ParseQuery.getQuery(ParseInstallation.class);
parsePush.setQuery(parseQueryInstallation);
parsePush.setMessage("A new file has been Updated. Check it out!");
parsePush.sendInBackground(new SendCallback() {

    @Override
    public void done(ParseException arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(TAG, "SendCallback success:");
        if(arg0 == null)
        {
            Log.d(TAG,
                    "suceess push notification :");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d(TAG,
                    "failed push notification  :"
                            + arg0.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**- EDIT 2 - in response to Suresh Kumar's answer**
- For some reason, cloud code never works in my projects. It just doesn't identify any Cloud code and keeps it in red [as shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BStZe.png)

Comment: try ParseQuery<ParseInstallation> parseQueryInstallation = ParseQuery.getQuery(ParseInstallation.class); instead of ParseInstallation.getQuery();

Comment: @BradleyWilson thank you for your answer ^^ I tried replacing it (I edited it in my question) but it still did not work

Answer (score 1):

The better way to send push notification in Parse is through cloud code. Create a cloud function to send push notification and call that cloud function in android using ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground().

```
HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("recipientId", userObject.getObjectId());
params.put("message", message);
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("sendPushToUser", params, new FunctionCallback<String>() {
   void done(String success, ParseException e) {
       if (e == null) {
          // Push sent successfully
       }
   }
});
```

Take a look at this [link](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/the-dangerous-world-of-client-push/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer ^^ I edited my question in response to your answer